# Is Ubuntu Core mature enough for commercial production?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Our company is considering the use of Ubuntu Core for an IoT product build with the Beaglebone Black. I am trying to figure out how mature Snappy is, so that we don't attempt to go down a development road that is not yet ready for primetime.

Could anyone confirm if companies are using Ubuntu Core in production?

Comment: Since this is a Community support site, wouldn't you better consider contacting Canonical?

Comment: I agree with xangua. Canonical would be able to provide you with answers and possibly data much better rather than a community site.

Comment: Your company needs to get in contact with Canonical bizdev to discuss if shipping Ubuntu Core is right for your device and what level of support you want to have from Canonical for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are companies using Ubuntu Core in production (Dell being an example).

As mentioned, it's probably better for you to contact Canonical.

Try this [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/internet-of-things/contact-us)